# How to replace if/else with polymorphism in a class?

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

I've been reading about polymorphism, and was very interested by a java example which replaced a long switch statement by an abstract class which automatically chose the right sub-class to perform the requested action.

For example:

```js
// switch version
class Bird {
  // ...
  getSpeed(): number {
    switch (type) {
      case EUROPEAN:
        return getBaseSpeed();
      case AFRICAN:
        return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * numberOfCoconuts;
      case NORWEGIAN_BLUE:
        return (isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(voltage);
    }
    throw new Error("Should be unreachable");
  }
}

// polymorphism version
abstract class Bird {
  // ...
  abstract getSpeed(): number;
}

class European extends Bird {
  getSpeed(): number {
    return getBaseSpeed();
  }
}
class African extends Bird {
  getSpeed(): number {
    return getBaseSpeed() - getLoadFactor() * numberOfCoconuts;
  }
}
class NorwegianBlue extends Bird {
  getSpeed(): number {
    return (isNailed) ? 0 : getBaseSpeed(voltage);
  }
}

// Somewhere in client code
let speed = bird.getSpeed();
```

Avoiding long if/else statement nested in a class function (I know I can encapsulate this code in a different function for more readability, but in the end I will still have to deal with many if/else) and automatically switch to the right sub-class would be great!

How to do it in Javascript?

I wrote something like:

```js
// base
class Bird {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }
  greets() {
    switch (this.name) {
      case "gull":
        return console.log("it's a gull")
      case "sparrow":
        return console.log("it's a sparrow")
      case "dove":
        return console.log("it's a dove")
    }
  }
} 

const bird = new Bird("sparrow")
bird.greets()
// output: "it's a sparrow"

// my poor attempt:
class Bird {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }
  greets() { 
      throw new Error("not implemented"); 
  }
}

class Gull extends Bird {
  greets(){
    return console.log("it's a gull")
  }
}

class Sparrow extends Bird {
  greets(){
    return console.log("it's a sparrow")
  }
}

class Dove extends Bird {
  greets(){
    return console.log("it's a dove")
  }
}

const bird = new Bird("gull")
bird.greets()
// output: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'
```

How to achieve polymorphism with this simple bird class? I should of course extends Birds for Dove, Sparrow and Gull, but I want to only call the Bird controller in my code since I won't know which kind of bird I will end up with.

Thanks!

ps: if there isa simpler way to achieve this with functions I'dbe happy to hear from you about it too!

Answer (score 0):

Very close to the example you provided (an example):

```
class Bird {
  // ...
  getSpeed() { 
      throw new Error("not implemented"); 
  }
}

class European extends Bird {
  getSpeed() {
    return 15;
  }
}
class African extends Bird {
  getSpeed() {
    return 17;
  }
}
class NorwegianBlue extends Bird {
  getSpeed() {
    return (isNailed) ? 0 : 10;
  }
}

// Somewhere in client code - bird is an instance one of the classes that extends Bird
let speed = bird.getSpeed();
```

Or, if you want to use a syntax that is closer to what you posted, you can use [Typescript](https://medium.com/@raymondjohnson121/polymorphism-object-oriented-principles-in-typescript-b176995e5643)

Comment: I've folllowed the typescript example, but I can't use the class Bird. It seems I always have to use Gull, Sparrow or Dove. But the whole idea would be a to use only Bird and let it decide which class to call. I've done a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bush-owmt6?file=/src/Bird.ts

Comment: @DoneDeal0 that's because you're calling (inApp.tsx): `const bird = new Bird("gull");` and `Bird` is an abstract class - you can't create instances of an abstract class! what we should have done instead is: `const bird = new Gull();`

Comment: Yes, but it goes against my goal. I know how to instantiate class & sub-classes, but what I wanted was to allow an automatic switch to a sub-class in order to define specific sub-methods. For example, I receive a bird, I want to describe it, but depending on the bird, the description function could be very different. At the moment, I have a greet function with many if/else statements. I can't call specific subclasses here, because I can't know which kind of bird I'll receive.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 and this is exactly what you'll be able to do so I don't see how it goes against your goal.